# android app cannot download from tablet play store

Tags: android, tablet

I upload an to google play store.But it is not visible on tablets.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

i added these support screens to my manifest.What i should change/add ,in order to get the app in tabs?

Comment: Its for all of the tablets or for specific one only ??

Comment: @SalmanKhan it is for all tablets.

Comment: It is not working on galaxy tab3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're support screens definition looks fine, have you any permission there are not available for tablets, like sms permission?

An Workaround for you:

in you're Manifest declare the extra permission as following:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" > </uses-feature>
```

in you're Java Code you can/must handle this section in there you want to send the sms, you can do this with the following:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean hasTelephony = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

with this you can do the rest

Comment: I have sms permission.

Comment: I am checking telephony feature in code.While developing i tested app in nexus 7 tablet and it worked.Is this issue will come only after uploading?

Comment: I'm have a nexus 7 too and i had the same problem, add the required statement to you're manifest and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

just delete all supports screen then your app is automatically allow or support all devices.
This we do whenever we want to download our app on some special devices other wise no need to write this support screen

just do it once and see yourself :) best of luck dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your manifest file, its for Nexus 7 tablet, Nexus 7 has an unusual tvdpi density. So may be that is the problem you are facing.

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
```